# VR is not supported three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webvr

I am trying to integrate a VR using three.js and i added this things to my code:

```
import { VRButton } from "three/examples/jsm/webxr/VRButton.js";
```

and

```
document.body.appendChild(VRButton.createButton(renderer1));
renderer1.xr.enabled = true;
```

My problem is that:

[image]

I guess my issue is that i am in localhost and in webpack server and URL is:

http://localhost:8080/

which is not https and i learnt from the

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebXR_Device_API that webxr only works on https.

Is it because of https, if yes how can i solve this so that i can learn !!!
If no, what i need to do more !!!

Thank you

Comment: [This tool](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) would let you make an SSL cert, and assuming you know how to make your app use an SSL cert, that might work for you

Comment: Hi thank you now i have https://localhost:8080/ but still its shows VR not supported !!!

Comment: Where are you accessing the URL from? You have to have a VR headset go into localhost or download an extension that simulates one.

Comment: I generally use ngrok.io to tunnel back to my local machine from TLS endpoint.  indispensable for hitting SSL enabled sites on your local machine from the internet.